# How to click a button programmatically in Taipy

Tags: python, taipy

I have a button in Taipy that when clicked calls a function performing some tasks that can give a valid or invalid result. In case of having an invalid result, clicking on another button must simulate a click on the first button (I cannot click on the first button directly because it has some status variables defined!).

I solved it by calling the function created inside the function of the second button, putting an ID and any action strings but, how can I make this click action programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the description of your issue, it seems the best solution is already what you have done. Simulate a click is the same as calling the callback function.

Is this code below not a good solution?

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui, notify

issue_in_run = False

md = """
<|First button|button|on_action=run|active={not issue_in_run}|>

<|Simulate First button (run)|button|on_action=run_simulate|>
"""

def run(state):
    print("Running...")
    notify(state, "info", "Running...")

    if not state.issue_in_run:
        print("Error")
        notify(state, "error", "Error!")
        state.issue_in_run = True
    else:
        print("Finished!")
        notify(state, "success", "Finished!")
        state.issue_in_run = False

def run_simulate(state):
    print("Simulating the run")
    notify(state, "info", "Simulating the run")
    run(state)

Gui(md).run()
```